# How can I make the index column int32 when using read_csv?

Tags: pandas, indexing

I want to read a csv without an index and have the index be int32 automatically. But it seems no matter what I do with index_col=False, the result is int64:

```
df = pd.read_table("examples/test.bed", index_col=False, header=None, 
                   dtype={"Index": np.int32})

df.index.dtype
# dtype('int64')
```

Comment: You can't... pandas has their own dtype scheme, for performance reasons.

Comment: I get same problem with astype, so it seems not possible

Comment: This has been asked before I seem to recall